# How do I associate a value in a dictionary with a value in a nested dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I'm trying to figure out how to return the value for `participantId` when inputting the value for `summonerName`. I thought of something like `participantIdentities.index(...)` but I'm working with a list of dictionaries that contain nested dictionaries, so I'm really not sure on this.

Example:

Input: `dd god`

Output: `1`

```
"participantIdentities": [
        {
            "participantId": 1,
            "player": {
                "accountId": "g7cSjy8G4hMab3ayDaY8cqOSSjztYvktybRT_XgkBsJUSD0",
                "currentAccountId": "g7cSjy8G4hMab3ayDaY8cqOSSjztYvktybRT_XgkBsJUSD0",
                "currentPlatformId": "NA1",
                "matchHistoryUri": "/v1/stats/player_history/NA1/233825986",
                "platformId": "NA1",
                "profileIcon": 1453,
                "summonerId": "ICw1u2Kv-lHR_bjaNPa6BHbpwGT5rqJJJIVfiqcpbBdy9LM",
                "summonerName": "dd god"
            }
        },
        {
            "participantId": 2,
            "player": {
                "accountId": "ZJ3NohMpa_FZHHSxyFBOxjyuU6JpL-LEbctTPV2pDeuNbw",
                "currentAccountId": "oS_oSZLMTC3ZYVYiehAR6ZA4Gly-qq_WT_c5uXvQRRryzlw",
                "currentPlatformId": "NA1",
                "matchHistoryUri": "/v1/stats/player_history/EUW1/22181515",
                "platformId": "EUW1",
                "profileIcon": 3271,
                "summonerId": "PlJSBls3iy0emnKRlwFZqvye8Plwnbp5ngG_NJ6JQmDI1nE",
                "summonerName": "TSM Bjergsen"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
dict_ = {"participantIdentities": [
        {
            "participantId": 1,
            "player": {
                "accountId": "g7cSjy8G4hMab3ayDaY8cqOSSjztYvktybRT_XgkBsJUSD0",
                "currentAccountId": "g7cSjy8G4hMab3ayDaY8cqOSSjztYvktybRT_XgkBsJUSD0",
                "currentPlatformId": "NA1",
                "matchHistoryUri": "/v1/stats/player_history/NA1/233825986",
                "platformId": "NA1",
                "profileIcon": 1453,
                "summonerId": "ICw1u2Kv-lHR_bjaNPa6BHbpwGT5rqJJJIVfiqcpbBdy9LM",
                "summonerName": "dd god"
            }
        },
        {
            "participantId": 2,
            "player": {
                "accountId": "ZJ3NohMpa_FZHHSxyFBOxjyuU6JpL-LEbctTPV2pDeuNbw",
                "currentAccountId": "oS_oSZLMTC3ZYVYiehAR6ZA4Gly-qq_WT_c5uXvQRRryzlw",
                "currentPlatformId": "NA1",
                "matchHistoryUri": "/v1/stats/player_history/EUW1/22181515",
                "platformId": "EUW1",
                "profileIcon": 3271,
                "summonerId": "PlJSBls3iy0emnKRlwFZqvye8Plwnbp5ngG_NJ6JQmDI1nE",
                "summonerName": "TSM Bjergsen"
            }
        }
    ]
}

input_val = "dd god"
identities = dict_['participantIdentities']

for p in identities:
    if p['player']['summonerName'] == input_val:
        print(p['participantId']
```

With the for loop you can iterate through your list of dictionaries and your nested dictionaries are accessable like a more dimensional array:

dict['a']['b'][...]

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing your answer to add some explanation and details. While it might answer the question, just adding some code does not help OP or future community members understand the issue or solution.